# How implode correctly this array?

Tags: php, arrays, implode

I have this array (`$recip`):

```
Array
(
    [0] => 393451234567
    [1] => 393479876543
)
```

SMS API provider requires numbers in this format:

```
recipients[]=393334455666&recipients[]=393334455667
```

With

```
$recipients = implode('&recipients[]=',$recip);
```

I can obtain only this:

```
393471234567&recipients[]=393459876543
```

Missing first one "`recipients[]`" (overall, first one no require the "`&`" at all).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just append the initial `recipients[]=` to the front of your string:

```
$recipients = 'recipients[]=' . implode('&recipients[]=',$recip);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value){
    $array[$key] = (($key == 0) ? '' : '&').'recipients[]='.$value;
}
$result = implode('',$array);
```

A `foreach` loop allows you to conctenate your string.  I include a check to avoid appending the & on the first part of the string.

Pointing this out as an option, but the other way is simpler!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
vsprintf('recipients[]=%s&recipients[]=%s', $recip);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option

```
foreach ($recip as $ip){
    $array[] = 'recipients[]=' . $ip;
}
$result = implode('&',$array);
```